# Spring jdbcTemplate @transactional does not rollback for postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to use `@Transactional` in my project where I have two DML statements in one method.My first DML statement gets exceuted even when there is an exception right after the first statement.I want it to rollback.How do i do? I have tried in many ways but no help.

My applicationContext.xml file is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
">

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stats"></property>
    <property name="user" value="stats"></property>
    <property name="password" value="stats"></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
</bean>
```

My Service Interface is :

```
public interface AssignFAServicesInterface {
public int saveAssignedFA(final String[] CVListCode, final int     userCodeFA, final String randomNoColumn, final String[] tourFrom, final String[] tourTo);
}
```

My Service Implementation is:

```
@Service("assignFAServices")
public class AssignFAServices implements AssignFAServicesInterface{
@Autowired
AssignFADaoInterface assignFADaoInterface;
 @Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = java.lang.Exception.class)
public int saveAssignedFA(final String[] CVListCode, final int userCodeFA, final String randomNoColumn, final String[] tourFrom, final String[] tourTo) {
    return assignFADaoInterface.saveAssignedFA(CVListCode,userCodeFA,randomNoColumn,tourFrom,tourTo);
}
```

My DAO Implementation is

```
@Repository("assignFADao")
public class AssignFADao implements AssignFADaoInterface{

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
@Override
public int saveAssignedFA(final String[] CVListCode, final int userCodeFA, final String randomNoColumn, final String[] tourFrom, final String[] tourTo) {
    int successCV[];
    int successSV[];
    int flag = 0;
    String sqlUpdateCV = "";
    String sqlUpdateSV = "";
    try {
        sqlUpdateCV = "UPDATE cce_cropvillagelist SET usercodefa=? WHERE cvlistcode=?";
        sqlUpdateSV = "UPDATE cce_samplevillages SET randomnocolumn=?,tourfrom=?,tourto=?,levelreached='FA',statusofdocument='F' WHERE cvlistcode=?";
        successCV = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlUpdateCV, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setInt(1, userCodeFA);
                ps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(CVListCode[i]));
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return CVListCode.length;
            }
        });
        int a=Integer.valueOf("bvxv");
        if (successCV.length > 0) {
            flag = 1;
            successSV = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqlUpdateSV, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    if (!tourFrom[i].trim().equals("-")) {
                        ps.setString(1, randomNoColumn);
                        ps.setDate(2, tourFrom[i].length()==0?null:new java.sql.Date(DateAndTime.convertStringToDate(tourFrom[i]).getTime()));
                        ps.setDate(3, tourTo[i].length()==0?null:new java.sql.Date(DateAndTime.convertStringToDate(tourTo[i]).getTime()));
                        ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(CVListCode[i]));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return CVListCode.length;
                }
            });
            if (flag == 1) {
                System.out.println("FLAG"+flag);
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | DataAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in AssignFADao.saveAssignedFA(final int[] CVListCode, final int userCodeFA,final String randomNoColumn,final Date[] tourFrom,final Date[] tourTo) : " + ex);
    } finally {
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Please help.
First when I tried to use `@Transactional`,the project did not run and then asked for aopalliance jar.After adding that jar,the project is running but rollback does not occur.

Comment: Don't catch the exceptions or re-throw from catch block.

Comment: I tried removing the try catch block but still the first Update statement gets executed and no rollback occurs. Also i tried re-throwing the error but again the same thing happened

Comment: Don't handle exceptions, simply add throws Exception to the method signature.

Comment: Thank you Lovababu. But it is still not working ..I really cant understand why so?

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = java.lang.Exception.class)
```

You're al telling Spring that rollback the transaction whe an Exception is thrown but you're catching them

```
    catch (NumberFormatException | DataAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in AssignFADao.saveAssignedFA(final int[] CVListCode, final int userCodeFA,final String randomNoColumn,final Date[] tourFrom,final Date[] tourTo) : " + ex);
    }
```

So Spring never notice that an exception was thrown. You can remove the try/catch block or you can throw the exception again inside the try/catch block

```
catch (NumberFormatException | DataAccessException ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception in AssignFADao.saveAssignedFA(final int[] CVListCode, final int userCodeFA,final String randomNoColumn,final Date[] tourFrom,final Date[] tourTo) : " + ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think you're missing annotation-driven tag in your config file.

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

In this article there is a full example of what youré doing.

http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc

Comment: I tried removing the try catch block but still the first Update statement gets executed and no rollback occurs. Also i tried re-throwing the error but again the same thing happened

Comment: Thank you reos. But it is still not working ..I really cant understand why so?